# How to return an Enum using the addScalar() method with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have:

```
@Column(name = "UserType", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private UserType userType;
```

How to return this field by SQL request using addScalar() method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how you add an Enum to a SQLQuery

1. You define a properties object

   ```
   Properties params = new Properties();
   params.put("enumClass", "UserType");
   params.put("type", "12"); /*EnumType.STRING type = 12 */
   ```
2. You resolve your enum type:

   ```
   Type userEnumType = sessionFactory.getTypeHelper().custom(UserType.class, params);
   ```
3. You execute your query:

   ```
   List<SomeEntity> result = getSession().createSQLQuery("select e from SomeEntity ")
       .addScalar("userType", userEnumType)
       .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SomeEntity.class))
       .list();
   ```

Comment: I got error org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to instantiate custom type: UserType. Also some people put in custom method EnumType.class. Then I got same error: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to instantiate custom type: org.hibernate.type.EnumType.

Comment: UserType is also a Hibernate class. Are you sure you added a class named UserType.

Comment: Actually, I wrote UserType only for example. But I use full name to that class like: com.xxx.User.UserType, when put it to params.

Comment: I solved this, when move away UserType enumeration from User class. UserType must have its own java file, then all will be good. So I use next enumClass value: com.xxx.UserType. And also I put EnumType.class into custom method.

Comment: Does this work with hibernate 5? I used for prior hibernates but now the same code is failing? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039481/enum-property-fails-in-sql-transformation-for-hibernate-5

Comment: It should since `addScalar` method is still found in `SQLQuery`.

Comment: I actually asked a question on it see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039481/enum-property-fails-in-sql-transformation-for-hibernate-5. Help will be appreciated

Comment: This worked for me for non-Enum types too, although I didn't need the Properties param.  Thanks!

Comment: @bavon: use `sessionFactory.getTypeHelper().custom` instead of `new TypeLocatorImpl(new TypeResolver()).custom`

Comment: Everyone across the web just keeps copying and pasting `/*EnumType.STRING type = 12 */` but what's behind this?

Comment: It's an explanation, telling you might the magic number 12 means in this context. I suppose devs might wonder about it.

Comment: how to do for non-enum, how to do for normal class/pojo ?